# Complexity in Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

I was reading this page https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms and one of the points they wanted to focus was this one:

"Show that worse-case asymptotic behavior is not always the deciding factor in choosing an algorithm."

However I believe it is deciding because depending of the length of the array, one sort could be better than other one, and that's showed graphically by its asymptote. What do you think? thanks

Comment: The classic example is quicksort, which is commonly used as a sorting algorithm because it's fast and its *expected time* is O(N log N), even though its worst-case time is O(N^2)...  Although library implementations often have guards and fallbacks to make sure it stays O(N log N) for pathological data

Answer (score 1):

Often, there are problems for which one algorithm is *usually* faster than another algorithm, but for which the worst-case is asymptotically slower. Specifically, one algorithm may be faster for the particular data you are working with, even though it is asymptotically slower in the worst-case. Memory usage can also be a concern in some cases. A good example of this is quicksort versus mergesort. They both have an average runtime of O(n log n), but quicksort is usually faster. However, in the worst case, quicksort has a runtime of O(n^2). Additionally, mergesort traditionally requires O(n) of extra memory. There is an in-place variant, but I think it is significantly slower. One other consideration is that mergesort is easier to parallelize.

In summary, algorithm choice depends on what data you are working with, multi-threading capacity, and memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Take Hashtables as an example. Generally they are very fast and insert, find, delete should work in constant time, which is great. That is why everyone uses them. However worst-case the hash-value of every single of your elements is the same and then the runtime gets much worse. There are ways to minimize the damage, like Cuckoo hashing etc, but in worst case the hash-table will either have worse runtime or worse memory consumption than other data structures. Generally you do not choose Hashtables because of their worst-case asymptotic runtime, because it is very very unlikely to happen.

Edit: Sorry I missed that the question is about algorithms not general runtime complexity. But I just need a small change: Assume you want an algorithm to find all duplicates in an array. You can just insert all elements into a HashSet. If you have a good hashing function, usually you will only have collisions if your elements are the same. So you would have O(n) runtime. But if you get a lot of false positives, where the elements have the same hash value even though they are different, your findDuplicates algorithm will take up to quadratic runtime. Again, those collision are very very unlikely to happen, so you would probably anyway take this approach.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world K and M are also a major factor, for example the animations doesn't take account of these factors. K is the constant factor in the algorithm and M is the memory cost.

This is the reason that Quicksort is mostly used everywhere, because not only do they have a good average, but the average has a very low K&M.

But then you have to mitigate the problem that the worst case is still pretty bad, use a fallback algorithm like [Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) does, if the recursion is too deep fall back to heap-sort or when the number of values gets low switch to insertion sort.